# Linear Regression and data manipulation

Tags: python, numpy

How could I improve the following code that runs a simple linear regression using matrix algebra?  I import a .csv file ([link here](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B0iAUHM7ljQ1dDM3UVJWaGZRZlNoNnFyZ3h1ekpydw)) called 'cdd.ny.csv', and perform the matrix calculations that [solve for the coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) (intercept and regressor) of Y = XB (i.e.,  $(X'X)^{-1}X'Y$):

```
import numpy
from numpy import *
import csv

df1 = csv.reader(open('cdd.ny.csv', 'rb'),delimiter=',')
tmp = list(df1)
b = numpy.array(tmp).astype('string')
b1 = b[1:,3:5]
b2 = numpy.array(b1).astype('float')

nrow = b1.shape[0]
intercept = ones( (nrow,1), dtype=int16 )

b3 = empty( (nrow,1), dtype = float )

i = 0
while i < nrow:
    b3[i,0] = b2[i,0]
    i = i + 1

X = numpy.concatenate((intercept, b3), axis=1)
X = matrix(X)

Y = b2[:,1]
Y = matrix(Y).T

m1 = dot(X.T,X).I
m2 = dot(X.T,Y)

beta = m1*m2

print beta

#[[-7.62101913]
# [ 0.5937734 ]]
```

To check my answer:

```
numpy.linalg.lstsq(X,Y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy
from numpy import *
import csv

df1 = csv.reader(open('cdd.ny.csv', 'rb'),delimiter=',')
tmp = list(df1)
b = numpy.array(tmp).astype('string')
b1 = b[1:,3:5]
b2 = numpy.array(b1).astype('float')
```

Firstly, I'd avoid all these abbreviated variables. It makes it hard to follow your code. You can also combine the lines a lot more

```
b2 = numpy.array(list(df1))[1:,3:5].astype('float')
```

That way we avoid creating so many variables.

```
nrow = b1.shape[0]
intercept = ones( (nrow,1), dtype=int16 )

b3 = empty( (nrow,1), dtype = float )

i = 0
while i < nrow:
    b3[i,0] = b2[i,0]
    i = i + 1
```

This whole can be replaced by `b3 = b2[:,0]`

```
X = numpy.concatenate((intercept, b3), axis=1)
X = matrix(X)
```

If you really want to use matrix, combine these two lines. But really, its probably better to use just array not matrix.

```
Y = b2[:,1]
Y = matrix(Y).T

m1 = dot(X.T,X).I
m2 = dot(X.T,Y)

beta = m1*m2



print beta
```

Comment: Thanks!  However, the line `X = numpy.concatenate((intercept, b3), axis=1)` now gives the error "ValueError: arrays must have same number of dimensions" -- this is the reason I added the while loop.  Any way around this?

Comment: @baha-kev, use `b3 = b2[:,0].reshape(-1, 1)`

Comment: Thanks; you mention it's probably better to use arrays - how do you invert an array?  The `.I` command only works on matrix objects.

Comment: @baha-kev, use the `numpy.lingalg.inv` function.